# Disable onfocus event for svg element

Tags: html, events, svg, focus

I realized that `tabindex=-1` doesn't work for `<svg></svg>` elements. Is there a way to disable the `focus` event for it? `preventDefault`, `stopPropagation`, `stopImmediatePropagation` also do not work.

Comment: FYI: This is a problem for IE 11 and MS Edge (all versions, currently through 13) and _for no other browser_. \*shakes fist\* Redmonndddd!

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`<svg focusable="false"></svg>` does this job.

Comment: In my tests, the focus event never occurred on svg elements, not even with `focusable="true"`. It seems though that IE always allows selecting svg elements by keyboard navigation (with the tab key) unless the `focusable` attribute is explicitly set to "false".

Comment: I'm confused. I can't find the `focusable` attribute in the SVG attribute index: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html

Comment: If anyone's wondering if they can deprecate this workaround, as of Edge 38.14393, it's no longer necessary: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8090208/