# IE 11 "tabindex" issue. have to press tab key twice to advance to the next input in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer, angular7, tabindex

It works fine in chrome and other browser but fails to work in IE browsers. When I try to run it chrome it works fine even if I give tabindex=1, but it fails to give the same desired output in IE browsers.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <ng-container *ngIf="namelist.length; else doElse">
       <li
        *ngFor="let title of namelist; index as i"
        #list
        class="some class XYZ"
        (click)="selectSomething(title)"
        (keydown.enter)="makeSelection(title)"
         >
        <div
          class="some class PQR"
          tabindex="0"
          (keydown.arrowup)="prev(listElements, i)"
          (keydown.arrowdown)="next(listElements, i)"
        >
          <span class="some class abcd">
            {{title}}
          </span>
         </div> 
        </li>
        </ng-container>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393144/how-to-prevent-svg-elements-from-gaining-focus-with-tabs-in-ie11 
try adding focusable=false to your `span` nested in your `div`.

Comment: It could be related to using an unordered list, or that they all share the same tabindex. You should probably try using a button instead of a div and remove tabindex, OR setting tabindex="{{i}}".

However, I should also mention we are well beyond Angular 7 now too, so you should upgrade if you haven't already.

Finally, if someone has answered your question, please mark it as answered, or provide your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a sample Angular project and added some text boxes with tab index. Based on my testing result I found that it is working fine in IE 11 browser.

Here is my testing result.

[image]

You can see that cursor is moving to the next control just with the single tab key press. I suggest you to create a new sample project and test this issue in it.

If it works fine then there can be some issue in your original project. It can help you to narrow down the issue and can be helpful for finding the cause for this issue.