# AngularJS wait for tag to load into DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm adding a google chart via the angular directive into a page and I would like to add an attribute to the  element it creates after it's loaded. What is the best way to ensure the element exists before attempting to add the attribute?

From looking around it seems like my directive that I have SHOULD work but does not:

```
.directive('vdfWidgetGoogleChart', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
return {
 restrict: 'E',
  //replace: true,
  templateUrl: 'widgetgooglechart.html',
  link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
      function addTabIndex () {
        elem.find('svg').attr({tabindex: -1});
      }
      $timeout(addTabIndex);
  },
  scope: {
    chartObject: '='
  }
}
```

Comment: how you are rendering `googlechart` element?

Comment: I'm just passing in the chart object using <div id="chartImage" role="img" google-chart chart="chartObject" style="{{cssStyle}}"></div>. I believe the answer below solves my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally when doing charting the easiest thing is to append the attribute to the SVG element, then you're being very angular as you aren't looking for elements.

Another option is create a controller and then a directive for the element SVG that requires that controller.  Then when you have SVG as a child of that directive your svg directive should get called. (This is a guess I haven't tried it)

```
<div controller-directive=".."><svg></svg></div>
```

Then your code would have the SVG when the controller exists as a parent.

Or you can simply adjust your code to look for the svg every 100ms or so until you find it.

```
function addTabIndex () {
    var svg = elem.find('svg');

    if (svg.length != 0)
        svg.attr({tabindex: -1});
    else
        $timeout(addTabIndex, 100);
}

$timeout(addTabIndex);
```

Comment: I ended up using the third option as I was using a 3rd party directive that makes a call to a service to get the html and I did not have access to what the google chart directive returns before it's on the page.

Comment: NOTE: Apparently '<SVG>' does not support tabIndex. According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646111/disable-onfocus-event-for-svg-element) I need to use focusable=false.